# AWSAathenaOperator output S3 name?

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow 2 and trying to use the AWSAthenaOperator. I can run the operator and it works, but I can't find any way to determine what the file names are that it wrote.

```
        task = AWSAthenaOperator(
            task_id="foo",
            database="mydb",
            query='select * from mytable limit 10;',
            aws_conn_id="athena_conn",
            output_location='s3://mybucket/myfolder',
        )
```

It drops files in `s3://mybucket/myfolder`, which is great, but how do I find out from the task output what those file names are? I need to then take those names and pass them to other tasks downstream.

I have been digging through the AWSAthenaOperator and AWSAthenaHook code that seems to do the work underneath, but I can't find where it stores that information or how I'd retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the path that you pass with `output_location` isn't unique. `output_location` is a [templated field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/37681bca0081dd228ac4047c17631867bba7a66f/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/athena.py#L58) so you can use `execution_date` to make it unique thus each task save the file to a different and known location so files from different tasks are not getting mixed also using that way you can use the path in downstream tasks.

```
    task = AWSAthenaOperator(
        task_id="foo",
        database="mydb",
        query='select * from mytable limit 10;',
        aws_conn_id="athena_conn",
        output_location='s3://mybucket/myfolder/{{ execution_date }}',
    )
```

Comment: That makes the folder unique, but the actual file in the folder gets some sort of random name. I think I have found that the id returned matches filename (minus suffix), so I'm seeing if I can get that to work.

Comment: @ChrisKessel it's the queryId https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html sadly this is not a parameter that you can configure. However you do have the value as it's being pushed to xcom https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8505d2f0a4524313e3eff7a4f16b9a9439c7a79f/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/athena.py#L123 so if you need to access the file from downstream task you can do that.